# Is there a way to ignore null values in a python list?

Tags: python, for-loop, google-api

I am working to pull calendar event attendees from google and finding that when an event doesnt have an attendee, the for loop fails.

```
    for calendar_id in me:
        count = 0
        #print('\n%s' % calendar_id)
        eventsResult = service.events().list(
            calendarId=calendar_id,
            timeMax=now,
            timeMin=end_date).execute()
            #orderBy='startTime').execute()
        #events = eventsResult.get('items', [])
        #events = eventsResult.get('items', [])

        events = service.events().list(calendarId=calendar_id).execute()
        events = events.get('items', [])
```

```
        for event in events:
            start = event['start'].get('dateTime')
            print('\n' + event['summary'] + " " + "(Calendar - " + calendar_id + ")")
            for attendees in event['attendees']:
                attid = event.get('attendees')
                atte = attendees.get('email')
                try:
                    attid = event.get('attendees')
                except Exception as e:
                    print("No attendees", e)
                try:
                    atte = attendees.get('email')
                except Exception as e:
                    print("No email found", e)
```

Comment: if event is a dictionary: if not "attendees" in attandees: continue

Comment: can u show what is event?

Comment: I tried what DrEichenbach said with no success:
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Calendar_Trial.py", line 102, in <module>
    main()
  File "Calendar_Trial.py", line 91, in main
    for attendees in event['attendees']:
KeyError: 'attendees'```

Answer (score 3):

This will help your for loop to continue

```
for attendees in event['attendees']:
    try:
        attid = event.get(attendees)
    except Exception as e:
        print("No attendees", e)
    try:
        atte = attendees.get('email')
    except Exception as e:
        print("No email found", e)
```

Comment: I am getting the same error as above. 

```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Calendar_Trial.py", line 111, in <module>
    main()
  File "Calendar_Trial.py", line 100, in main
    for attendees in event['attendees']:
KeyError: 'attendees'```

Comment: Edited my for loop above

Comment: change event.get(attendees) instead of event.get('attendees')

Comment: Made the change and no getting a little further:

```No attendees unhashable type: 'dict'
No attendees unhashable type: 'dict'
No attendees unhashable type: 'dict'```

Comment: can you share your event dict

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! I added it up top